# SystemJS import chart.js in index.html

Tags: visual-studio, angular, node-modules, systemjs

I am new to angularjs (specially angular js2).

I am confused with SystemJS importing / configurations.

I have my application (angularjs2) which works ok. I am developing it with Visual Studio.

I have set up the package.json which loads in node_modules my necessary stuff. 
In my case I would like to use chart.js

snippet from **package.json file**

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.26",
    "zone.js": "0.6.11",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6",
    "jquery": "2.2.3",
    "font-awesome": "4.5.0",
    "toastr": "2.1.2",
    "chart.js": "2.0.2"    
  },
```

In my Index.html I have the following :

```
<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                app: {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });

        System.import('app/main')
              .then(null, console.error.bind(console));

        $(document).ready(function () {
            window.toastr = toastr;
            setTimeout(function () {
                toastr.options = {
                    closeButton: true,
                    progressBar: true,
                    showMethod: 'slideDown',
                    timeOut: 2500
                };
                toastr.success('Welcome to the APP');

            }, 1300);
        });
    </script>
```

How Chart  JS is imported:

```
 <!-- ChartJS-->
 <!--version1: OLD ChartJS importing WORKS ok--> 
 <!--<script src="scripts/plugins/chartJs/Chart.min.js"></script>-->

 <!--version2: This kind of importing does not work-->
 <script src="node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

Note:

I have a **toastr** which is also imported from node_modules in this way:

```
   <!-- Toastr -->
    <script src="node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.js"></script>
```

But it is working ok.

The node_modules folder is not included in my solution

[image]

I am going to use it in a component (later in a separate directive - according to best approach)

[image]

At that line

```
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineData, options);
```

it is complaining about:

```
ReferenceError: Chart is not defined
    at DashboardComponent.execute.DashboardComponent.createLinearChart
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After **Chart.js** was released in version **2.2.1** and **Angular 2** is at **RC4** It is possible to use **chart.js** in following manner:

```
//package.json
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",

    "chart.js": "2.2.1",
    "...ETC"
```

Import from node_modules:

```
//Index.html
<script src="node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"></script>
```

Use in action:

```
this.chart = new Chart(ctx, { type: 'line', data: data, options: chartOptions });
```

More details about "How to use" see in this post: [chart.js - Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target (angular2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38714958/chart-js-supplied-parameters-do-not-match-any-signature-of-call-target-angula)

Comment: is there anyway to remove the line from the index.html and put it in the systemjs.config.js file?

Comment: @reza, can't answer that. I switched to webpack and I am using vendors file for injection of 3rd party libs. Maybe the answer from Thierry is OK for you?

Answer (score 1):

I would configure the library within SystemJS this way since the library supports CommonJS:

```
System.config({
  map: {
    chart: 'node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js'
  },
  packages: {
    (...)
  }
});
```

This way you will be able to import the `Chart` object:

```
import Chart from 'chart';

(...)
var myNewChart = new Chart(...);
```

Comment: I set it in this way: `map: { 'chart': 'node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js'  } `

in my `dashboard.component.ts` is complaining at `import Chart from 'chart';` is complaining that **Cannot find module 'chart'**

Comment: and in browser console: a lot of 
`GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/chart.js/dist/charts/Chart.PolarArea 404 (Not Found)`
`GET http://localhost:3000/chartjs-color 404 (Not Found)` 
`GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/chart.js/dist/charts/Chart.Bar 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: That's a bit strange because chart.js relies on JS files (loaded using `require(...)`) that aren't located into the dist folder :-(

Comment: You could try to add this into the `map` block: `'chart/charts': 'node_modules/chart.js/src/charts`. Just a guess ;-)