# Error says Chart is not defined

Tags: typescript, angular, chart.js

I tried to add ChartJS to Angular2, but it keeps saying that Chart is not defined. I installed the ChartJS typings and referenced it. I also added the chartjs script to the index.html file. What am I doing wrong?

```
/// <reference path="../../website/typings/main/ambient/chart/index.d.ts" />
import {Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[chart]'
})
export class ChartDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
        //el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
        var data = {
            labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
                },
                {
                    label: "My Second dataset",
                    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
                }
            ]
        };
        var ctx: any = el.nativeElement.getContext("2d");
        var lineChart = new Chart(ctx);
        ////var lineChartOptions = areaChartOptions;
        ////lineChartOptions.datasetFill = false;
        lineChart.Line(data);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

This is my index.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>DBL Information Systems</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/chartjs/chart.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                app: {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });
        System.import('app/main')
                .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</head>

<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my typings folder structure:

[image]

Comment: How do you add chartjs into your `index.html` file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the `Chart` class from an `import` clause:

```
import {Chart} from 'chartjs';
```

The `something` depends on the way you configured SystemJS.

The typings you include is only used for compilation and autocompletion within your IDE.

**Edit**

The corresponding SystemJS configuration for the chartjs library is:

```
System.config({
  map: {
    chartjs: 'node_modules/chartjs/chart.js'
  },
  (...)
});
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/IA2LojT2CXV9qcCDOdBl?p=preview.

**Edit2**

Regarding typings, I would install the corresponding one this way:

- Install the library typings from npm

  ```
  npm install --save-dev retyped-chartjs-tsd-ambient
  ```
- Importing the typings using typings

  ```
  typings install --save --ambient file:node_modules/retyped-chartjs-tsd-ambient/chart.d.ts
  ```
- There is still an error since the d.ts file doesn't declare a module name. To fix that you can wrap the declaration of this file with a `declare module` clause:

  ```
  declare module 'chartjs' {
    interface ChartDataSet {
      label: string;
    (...)
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I added the index.html file to my question. My Chart library does not contain a .ts file. Am I still able to import the Chart class?

Comment: Thanks! I think that you need to configure charjs.js in the SystemJS configuration. See this question for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36693803/systemjs-import-chart-js-in-index-html/36694035#36694035.

Comment: I added map: {chart: 'node_modules/chartjs/chart.js'} and it says chart not found. This is the same issue as in your linked stackoverflow issue, but I am not able to resolve it....

Comment: Which URL is loaded and fails?

Comment: Just: import Chart from 'chart'; As suggested in your link

Comment: It seems that there are two packages in npm: chart.js and chartjs ;-) Which one do you use? I think that configurations for them...

Comment: Oh great! So I think that the configuration is: `map: { chart: 'node_modules/chartjs/chart.js' }`

Comment: Yes, I thought so as well, that's the code I used. But it is not recognizing it.
app/chart.directive.ts(2,19): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'chart'.

Comment: Could you try: `import * as Chart from 'chart';` or `import Chart from 'chart';`?

Comment: If you print the `Chart` object with èconsole.log(Chart);`, what do you see?

Comment: I copy pasted it, but it is still saying app/chart.directive.ts(2,21): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'chart'.

Comment: Oh it's a compilation problem related to typings. You could try to rename `chart` to `chartjs` into the SystemJS configuration and the import... I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Could you provide the list of folders and files under the `typings` folder?

Comment: Could you install this typings: https://github.com/retyped/chartjs-tsd-ambient instead of yours? In this case I think that `chart` for the module name should work...

Comment: Ok, I installed it. It installed under the node_modules folder. I replaced it into the typings folder, but still no success unfortunately

Comment: I think that you need to import the installed module within typings as well. I updated my answer ;-)