# chart.js - Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target (angular2)

Tags: angular, chart.js, typescript-typings

I am using `chart.js version 2.2.1` in my `angular 2` app.

When call the constructor of `Chart` an error is displayed:
`Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target`. 
And `npm start` command does not compile the app.

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: this.chartType,
    data: chartData,
    options: chartOptions
});
```

By using the above method the chart is drawn in browser.
(But I have to: 1) comment the code which creates the **Chart**, 2) run `npm start`, 
3) uncomment the code)

I have reinstalled `TypeScript Definitions (d.ts) for chartjs`

In `chart.d.ts` is that signature of `Chart`:

```
interface Chart {
    Line(data: LinearChartData, options?: LineChartOptions): LinearInstance;
    Bar(data: LinearChartData, options?: BarChartOptions): LinearInstance;
    Radar(data: LinearChartData, options?: RadarChartOptions): LinearInstance;

    PolarArea(data: CircularChartData[], options?: PolarAreaChartOptions): CircularInstance;
    Pie(data: CircularChartData[], options?: PieChartOptions): CircularInstance;
    Doughnut(data: CircularChartData[], options?: PieChartOptions): CircularInstance;
}

declare var Chart: {
    new (context: CanvasRenderingContext2D): Chart;
    defaults: {
        global: ChartSettings;
    }
};
```

According to that Typescript Definition I have to create the Chart in that way:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(chartData, chartOptions);
```

By calling in this way the `Chart` instance does not contain `Line(/*...*/)` function.

How can I fix the problem?

*I have installed typings for chart.js as is suggested here:* 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/chartjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the problem listed in question:

---

Q:
*When call the constructor of Chart an error is displayed:*

- `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`
- And `npm start` command does not compile the app.

---

for the setup (angular2-rc4, chart.js-2.2.1),
In the component where the `Chart` is instantiated declare the global variable 
Chart: `declare var Chart: any;`

*The whole code is bellow:*

```
import { Component, Input, Output, 
         EventEmitter, ElementRef, 
         Inject, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';


declare var Chart: any; //THIS LINE resolves the problem listed in question!!! 


@Component({
    selector: 'my-chart',  
    template: `<canvas height="{{chartHeight}}"></canvas>`,
    styles: [`:host { display: block; }`]
})

export class LinearChartDirective implements AfterViewInit {
    @Input() chartData: Array<any>;
    @Input() chartXAxisLabels: Array<any>;

    @Input() showLegend: boolean;
    @Input() legendLabel: string;
    @Input() chartHeight: number;

    chart: any;

    constructor( @Inject(ElementRef) private element: ElementRef) {    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {        
        let context = this.element.nativeElement.children[0].getContext('2d');
        this.createChart(ctx);
    }

    createChart(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {    
        if(!this.chartData)
            return;

        let data = {
            labels: this.chartXAxisLabels,
            datasets: [{
                label: this.legendLabel,
                data: this.chartData,

                backgroundColor: ['rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'],
                borderColor: ['rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)'],
                borderWidth: 1,
                lineTension: 0, // set to 0 means - No bezier

                pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                pointBorderWidth: 1,
                pointHoverRadius: 5,
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                pointRadius: 2,
                pointHitRadius: 10
            }]
        };

        let chartOptions = {           
            legend: { display: this.showLegend !== undefined ? this.showLegend : false },

            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
            scales: { yAxes: [{ ticks: { beginAtZero: true } }] }
        };

        //next line is no more complaining about "Supplied parameters..."
        this.chart = new Chart(ctx, { type: 'line', data: data, options: chartOptions });
    }  
}
```