# angular 2 http get Understanding "supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target"

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

i try do understand why the compiler throws the "supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target" Error in this code, in Angular 2.0 compiled in es6.

The Error is at the line  `this.observer_data = this.http.get(this.get_all_buchungen_url ...`

The service provides an observable object of the "BuchungsPos" Type witch will be initialized with the `load_and_init_buchungen()` function.

service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ReadBuchungenService {

    public observer_data : Observable<BuchungPos>;
    constructor (private http : Http ) {}

    public load_and_init_buchungen(timestamp : number) {

        let params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.set('timestamp', String(timestamp));

        this.observer_data = 
            this.http.get(this.get_all_buchungen_url, { search: params })
            .map(response => response.json());

        return;
    }

...
```

The imported BuchngsPos Class looks like:

```
export class BuchungPos {

    constructor(public id : number,
                public date : string,
                public name : boolean
    ) {}
}
```

in the app.component

```
constructor(public readDataservice : ReadBuchungenService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.readDataservice.load_and_init_buchungen(this.startTime);
    }
```

and use the object in other components:

```
export class TagComponent implements OnInit {

    private buchungPos : BuchungPos;

    constructor( private readBuchungenService : ReadBuchungenService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.readBuchungenService.observer_data.subscribe(
            function (data) {
               this.buchungPos = data.data;
            }.bind(this)
        );
    }
}
```

I already searched for this issue and and found some answers but they did not helped me to understand it.

[angular2: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target, even though i have all the needed params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39203902/angular2-supplied-parameters-do-not-match-any-signature-of-call-target-even-th)

[chart.js - Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target (angular2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38714958/chart-js-supplied-parameters-do-not-match-any-signature-of-call-target-angula)

Comment: Instead of using `funtion (..) { ... }.bind()` you can just use `(..) => { ...}`

Answer (score 0):

I found the error by my self, i have to use the latest rxjs version, here the package json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "^2.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^2.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "^3.1.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.26"
  }
```